# Cast buffer to pointer Structure

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, structure

I have two structure

```
struct TbtStreamHeader
{
    short MsgLen;
    short StreamId;
    int SeqNo;

    TbtStreamHeader()
    {
        MsgLen = StreamId = 0;
        SeqNo = 0;
    }
};

struct Multicast_OrderMsg
{
    char MsgType; ///'N', 'X', 'M'
    long long Timestamp;
    double OrderId;
    int Token;
    char OrderType;
    int Price;
    int Quantity;
    string ToString()
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss<<MsgType<<'|'<<Timestamp<<'|'<<(long long)OrderId<<"|0|"<<Token<<'|'<<OrderType<<'|'<<Price<<'|'<<Quantity;
        return ss.str();
    }

};
```

I am reading a file using ifstream, filling that file into the structure object because file is not into the format of structure, then copy the structure into char buffer. Here is the code for better understanding.

```
TbtStreamHeader hdr;
Multicast_OrderMsg oMsg;
hdr.MsgLen = 38;
hdr.StreamId = streamID;
hdr.SeqNo = 0;
bool firstLine = true;
    while(ifs1)
    {
        if (!getline(ifs1, str1)) break;
        istringstream ss(str1);
        v1.clear();
        while(ss)
        {
            string s1;
            if(!getline( ss, s1, '|' ))
            {
                break;
            }
            v1.push_back(s1);
        }
        if(firstLine)
        {
            firstLine = false;
            seq = atoi(v1[1].c_str());
            hdr.SeqNo = seq;
            getline(ifs1, str1);
        }
        else
        {
            char tempData[38];
            int tempBufOffset=0;
            hdr.SeqNo++;
            oMsg.OrderId = atoll(v1[0].c_str());
            oMsg.Token = atoi(v1[1].c_str());
            oMsg.OrderType = v1[2][0];
            oMsg.Price = atoi(v1[3].c_str());
            oMsg.Quantity = atoi(v1[4].c_str());
            oMsg.MsgType = 'N';
            memcpy(tempData, &hdr, 8);
            tempBufOffset += 8;
            memcpy(tempData+tempBufOffset, oMsg, 30);
            Multicast_OrderMsg* oMsgT = (Multicast_OrderMsg*)tempData+8; //Not able to caste
            cout<<oMsgT->ToString()<<endl;
            tempBufOffset += 30;
            mcastTbt.streams[0].RecoveryPacket(tempData);
        }
    }
```

Here `cout<<` showing me segmentation fault. I am not able to understanding what wrong it is..?

Comment: Not to be rude, but I feel this is a messy and dangerous use of pointers casting. Why don't you proper struct arrays to store your structs instead of a char array?

Answer (score 0):

At the location `tempData+8` are no `Multicast_OrderMsg` objects, dereferencing such pointer is undefined behaviour as it violates the strict aliasing rule.

But that on itself does not **usually** cause seg. faults, the reason is `tempData` is not big enough to store the aliased `Multicast_OrderMsg` object. On most implementation the types require to be aligned at least to their size, which causes padding:

```cpp
struct Multicast_OrderMsg
{
    char MsgType; //        1
    // Padding              7
    long long Timestamp;//  8
    double OrderId;//       8
    int Token;//            4
    char OrderType;//       1
    // Padding              3
    int Price;//            4
    int Quantity;//         4
};
```

Making the structure 40 bytes long, you only have space for 30. So the printing tries to access memory locations not belonging to you, hence the segfault.

Comment: I have used it tempData size upto 1024 bytes still result same

Comment: Then debug your code and see what exactly causes the exception. Bottom line is the cast is still UB, don't do it. If you need more help, post a [mcve] and also explain why do you need to write it like you did.

Comment: oMsgT->MsgType is the first thing to be print that is showing seg fault

Comment: Yes, that is possible, the cast is Undefined Behaviour, you cannot dereference the pointer, it is as simple as that.